# hide IP from webserver software and PHP

Tags: onion-services, linux, ip-address-leak

I want to setup a hidden service but I would like to hide the IP from the webserver software (nginx here) and PHP, but I'm not sure how to do it?

If nginx and PHP can't know the current server IP, no leak is possible

From my understanding a software can only know the machine IP with the help of a remote host.

Comment: Can you explain your question a bit more, please?

Answer (score 0):

Well, not exactly with the direct help - a stuff like scanning syste, configs can also work. For hidden service - not just for securing the IP's - I do recommend you to use an isolated VM: Virtualbox, KVM or Xen will do the job properly and all of them are free and open-source